# Prettier: error formatting valid handlebars/html code

Tags: visual-studio-code, attributes, handlebars.js, prettier, hbs

This is my first interaction on Stackoverflow!

Is there a way, under vscode, using prettier or another solution, to format the following `handlebars/HTML` template:

```
<div 
  {{#if myOnclick}}
    onclick="{{myOnclick}}"
  {{/if}}
>
  Click me!
</div>
```

which actually gives the error: `SyntaxError: A block may only be used inside an HTML element or another block.`

The playground is available [here](https://prettier.io/playground/#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).

I understand that prettier uses `glimmer` under the hood, and, quoting from the [release notes](https://prettier.io/blog/2021/05/09/2.3.0.html): "This means Prettier won’t format Handlebars files that can’t be parsed into such a tree".

I think that this is the case here, but I suspect also that this is a fairly common use case.

Obviously, I can live without an auto-formatter, but it is better with it ;)

Any help on that topic would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you find a solution ?